# Where is the WeBlog toolbar

Tags: sitecore, weblog

I have a dev sitecore install where I installed the WeBlog package and added WeBlog weblog. Everything is setup and works fine on the dev machine.

When I sync using hedgehog and TFS with another machine the weblog appears but the WeBlog toolbar in edit mode (with the add new entry, add category) buttons does not appear.

What am I missing? What am I not syncing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you sync across the Sitecore items added to the `core` database? Open the zip you downloaded and check the items added to the core database under `items\core\sitecore\content\Applications\`

Comment: yep, this is it... I was looking in the master db only... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the toolbar definition was in the core database under `\content\applications\webedit\ribbons\webedit\weblog`